# NSRegularExpression to match and replace all occurencies (porting from Ruby lang)

Tags: objective-c, ruby, regex, nsregularexpression

I have troubles while trying to port the Ruby code to the ObjC code

Ruby:

```
clean_url = original_url.gsub(/\\u0026[^&]*/, "")
```

Execution:

```
original_url = http://r6---sn-hvaquxaxjvh-3p8l.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?upn=StTvWU7n7N0&ms=au&expire=1368735912&id=e934f5f5c0743533&fexp=919374,909926,916713,916611,901474,924605,901208,929123,929915,929906,925714,929119,931202,928017,912518,911416,906906,904476,930807,919373,906836,933701,900345,926403,912711,929606,910075&sparams=cp,id,ip,ipbits,itag,ratebypass,source,upn,expire&sver=3&cp=U0hVTVdOU19GTENONV9PSFdKOnZFc0Uyc21YTVQw&ratebypass=yes&mv=m&source=youtube&itag=43&newshard=yes&mt=1368711866&ipbits=8&ip=92.114.198.83&key=yt1\u0026quality=medium\u0026type=video/webm&signature=AB8A6D618BDC38AF9D2E81916B863B724D2F12B6.8876CF4E106820B6443B4B06055BF90FD74B5794\u0026fallback_host=tc.v19.cache7.c.youtube.com,url=http://r6---sn-hvaquxaxjvh-3p8l.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?upn=StTvWU7n7N0

clean_url = http://r6---sn-hvaquxaxjvh-3p8l.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?upn=StTvWU7n7N0&ms=au&expire=1368735912&id=e934f5f5c0743533&fexp=919374,909926,916713,916611,901474,924605,901208,929123,929915,929906,925714,929119,931202,928017,912518,911416,906906,904476,930807,919373,906836,933701,900345,926403,912711,929606,910075&sparams=cp,id,ip,ipbits,itag,ratebypass,source,upn,expire&sver=3&cp=U0hVTVdOU19GTENONV9PSFdKOnZFc0Uyc21YTVQw&ratebypass=yes&mv=m&source=youtube&itag=43&newshard=yes&mt=1368711866&ipbits=8&ip=92.114.198.83&key=yt1&signature=AB8A6D618BDC38AF9D2E81916B863B724D2F12B6.8876CF4E106820B6443B4B06055BF90FD74B5794
```

Ruby code works as expected.

ObjC code:

```
NSError *error;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\u0026[^&]*" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

NSString *originalUrl = @"http://r6---sn-hvaquxaxjvh-3p8l.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?upn=StTvWU7n7N0&ms=au&expire=1368735912&id=e934f5f5c0743533&fexp=919374,909926,916713,916611,901474,924605,901208,929123,929915,929906,925714,929119,931202,928017,912518,911416,906906,904476,930807,919373,906836,933701,900345,926403,912711,929606,910075&sparams=cp,id,ip,ipbits,itag,ratebypass,source,upn,expire&sver=3&cp=U0hVTVdOU19GTENONV9PSFdKOnZFc0Uyc21YTVQw&ratebypass=yes&mv=m&source=youtube&itag=43&newshard=yes&mt=1368711866&ipbits=8&ip=92.114.198.83&key=yt1\\u0026quality=medium\\u0026type=video/webm&signature=AB8A6D618BDC38AF9D2E81916B863B724D2F12B6.8876CF4E106820B6443B4B06055BF90FD74B5794\\u0026fallback_host=tc.v19.cache7.c.youtube.com,url=http://r6---sn-hvaquxaxjvh-3p8l.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?upn=StTvWU7n7N0";

NSString *cleanUrl = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:originalUrl options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [originalUrl length]) withTemplate:@"bla"];
```

NOTICE on withTemplate:@"bla" because without it we cannot see where is the problem.

Execution:

```
clean_url = http://r6---sn-hvaquxaxjvh-3p8l.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?upn=StTvWU7n7N0blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary problem is your regular expression. It needs to be:

```
@"\\\\u0026[^&]*"
```

You want two backslashes in the regular expression. In C and Objective-C, a backslash needs to be escaped with another backslash. This means the string needs 4 backslashes.

Here's a simpler approach if you only need to process one string:

```
NSString *originalUrl = @"http://r6---sn-hvaquxaxjvh-3p8l.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?upn=StTvWU7n7N0&ms=au&expire=1368735912&id=e934f5f5c0743533&fexp=919374,909926,916713,916611,901474,924605,901208,929123,929915,929906,925714,929119,931202,928017,912518,911416,906906,904476,930807,919373,906836,933701,900345,926403,912711,929606,910075&sparams=cp,id,ip,ipbits,itag,ratebypass,source,upn,expire&sver=3&cp=U0hVTVdOU19GTENONV9PSFdKOnZFc0Uyc21YTVQw&ratebypass=yes&mv=m&source=youtube&itag=43&newshard=yes&mt=1368711866&ipbits=8&ip=92.114.198.83&key=yt1\\u0026quality=medium\\u0026type=video/webm&signature=AB8A6D618BDC38AF9D2E81916B863B724D2F12B6.8876CF4E106820B6443B4B06055BF90FD74B5794\\u0026fallback_host=tc.v19.cache7.c.youtube.com,url=http://r6---sn-hvaquxaxjvh-3p8l.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?upn=StTvWU7n7N0";
NSString *cleanURL = [originalURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\\u0026[^&]*" withString:@"" options: NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, originalURL.length)];
```

If you need to process multiple strings with the regular expression then using `NSRegularExpression` is more efficient.

Comment: Rats!  Too fast for me :).  +1 For the answer I was about to write.